# C# thread functions not properly sharing a static data member

Tags: c#, multithreading, static-members

I have a class as following

```
public class ScheduledUpdater
{
    private static readonly object lockingObject = new object();
    private static Queue<int> PendingIDs = new Queue<int>();
    private static bool UpdateThreadRunning = false;
    private static bool IsGetAndSaveScheduledUpdateRunning = false;
    private static DataTable ScheduleConfiguration;
    private static Thread updateRefTableThread;
    private static Thread threadToGetAndSaveScheduledUpdate;
    public static void ProcessScheduledUpdates(int ID)
    {
        //do some stuff
        // if ( updateRefTableThread not already running)
        // execute updateRefTableThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateSchedulingRefTableInThrear));
        // execute updateRefTableThread.Start();
        //do  some stuff
        ***[1]***
        GetAndSaveScheduledUpdate(ID)
    }
    private static void UpdateSchedulingRefTableInThrear()
    {
        //if(updateRefTableThread==true)
        //    return;
        // updateRefTableThread = true
        do{
        UpdateSchedulingRefTable(); 
        Thread.sleep(800000);
        }while(updateRefTableThread);
        //updateRefTableThread = false;
    }
    public static void UpdateSchedulingRefTable()
    { 
        // read DB and update ScheduleConfiguration 
        string query = " SELECT ID,TimeToSendEmail FROM TBLa WHERE MODE = 'WebServiceOrder' AND BDELETE = false ";
        clsCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new clsCommandBuilder();
        DataSet ds = commandBuilder.GetDataSet(query);
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            List<string> lstIDs = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                lstIDs.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                if (LastEmailSend.Contains(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()))
                    LastEmailSend[ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TimeToSendEmail"].ToString();
                else
                    LastEmailSend.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TimeToSendEmail"].ToString());
            }
            if (lstIDs.Count > 0)
            {
                string Ids = string.Join(",", lstIDs.ToArray()).Trim(',');
                dhDBNames dbNames = new dhDBNames();
                dbNames.Default_DB_Name = dbNames.ControlDB;
                dhGeneralPurpose dhGeneral = new dhGeneralPurpose();
                dhGeneral.StringDH = Ids;
                DataSet result = commandBuilder.GetDataSet(dbNames, (object)dhGeneral, "xmlGetConfigurations");
                if (result != null && result.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    ***[2]***
                    Monitor.Enter(lockingObject);
                    if (ScheduleConfiguration != null)
                        ScheduleConfiguration.Clear();
                    ScheduleConfiguration = result.Tables[0];
                    Monitor.Exit(lockingObject);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void GetAndSaveScheduledUpdate(int ID)
    {
        ***[3]***
        //use ScheduleConfiguration 
        Monitor.Enter(lockingObject);
        if (ScheduleConfiguration == null)
        {
            UpdateSchedulingRefTable();
            Monitor.Exit(lockingObject);

        }
        else
            Monitor.Exit(lockingObject);
        Monitor.Enter(lockingObject);
        DataRow[] result = ScheduleConfiguration.Select("ID = "+ID);
        Monitor.Exit(lockingObject);
        //then for each result row, i add this to a static Queue PendingIDs

    }
}
```

The function `UpdateSchedulingRefTable` can be called any time from outside world (for instance if someone updates the schedule configuration manually)
`ProcessScheduledUpdates` is called from a windows service every other minute.
Problem:
Datatable `ScheduleConfiguration` is updated in the `UpdateSchedulingRefTable` (called from outside world - say manually) but when i try to use Datatable `ScheduleConfiguration` in `GetAndSaveScheduledUpdate`, i get the older version of values....

What am I missing in this stuff???

**About EDIT: I thought the stuff i have not shown is quite obvious and possibly not desired, perhaps my structure is wrong :) and sorry for incorrect code previously, i made a simple function call as a thread initialization... sorry for my code indentation too because i don't know how to format whole block...**

**Edit 2**: `ProcessScheduledUpdates` is called from a windows service (say every second).
I am first hitting point **[1]** (it will automatically hit point **[2]** and update `ScheduleConfiguration`), then i **manually update DB** and hit point **[2]**. Then i hit point **[1]** again to just check the status
My problem is now, that i get two entirely different copies of `ScheduleConfiguration` at point [1] and [2].

**Edit 3** I think my question is invalid; i wanted to share data betweena a windows form click and a windows service. No matter how many shared things i have, atleast the address space will be different... My bad...

Comment: Could you add the code, where you manipulate the DataTable?

Comment: You're not posting the code, that communicates with the database, I would presume, that the problem lies there, because IF one method updates data in the database AND another method later reads data from the database - there should be no problems, whether your variables ar static, or not.

Comment: `ProcessScheduledUpdates` is called from a windows service and **[2]** is crossed by a thread ... does it make any difference ??? (could be a really stupid question but things are not working for me :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one thing there's no sign that you've got any memory barriers anywhere which would ensure that any writes are fully "flushed" to main memory, and that reads *go* to main memory instead of using registers etc. Basically you shouldn't use fields shared between threads without *some* sort of protection.

Now that's a theoretical risk to some extent - it's not clear that that's *actually* the problem, although it's certainly a real possibility. I strongly suspect there's another problem, but in the code that you haven't shown us. Do you have diagnostics to indicate that the first thread definitely wrote to `ScheduleConfiguration`?

Comment: well, i just intentionally didn't check any memory barriers. i wanted to check while debugging... assuming that everything is safe...

Comment: @Umer: It's not safe, basically. You should either use locking or some other sort of memory barrier, when changing shared variables. But my *guess* is that actually your `UpdateSchedulingRefTable` method simply isn't going into the section which ends up setting the variable - it has to satisfy various criteria before getting there.

Comment: is it possible that even while debugging, such problem could occue (i assume no because each step is executed on our control) ???

Comment: @Umer: Probably not - I strongly suspect it's a different problem, e.g. no tables being found.